# Make the source code from one code block the input to another code block in Emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, literate-programming

I'm getting started with org-mode and there's something I'd like to do that seems like it should be possible, but I'm having trouble figuring out.

Let me describe the scenario: I have some SQL code that I want to execute on a remote server. I currently have a python script that takes SQL code as a string and does this for me. Without org-mode, my work flow would be to start with a file like so:

```
echo "SELECT name, grade FROM students" >> basic_query.sql
```

and then I'd run:

```
$ python run_query.py basic_query.sql
```

To do this is in the org-mode setting, I could create a code block for the SQL:

```
#+NAME: basic_query 
#+BEGIN_SRC SQL 
SELECT name, grade FROM students 

#+END_SRC
```

And then I'd have a code block for the python calling function:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :export results
import sql_helper 
query_status = sql_helper.run_query(<<basic_query>>)  

#+END_SRC
```

Which I might use to create a table, process further, plot etc. Note the `<< >>` thing is not right, obviously---it's just an abuse of notation to indicate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can look at [this paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v46/i03), seen in [this blogpost](http://irreal.org/blog/?p=653).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have set up emacs/org-mode so that python code is enabled (`(python . t)` in `org-babel-do-load-languages`), you are almost there, I changed your example to

```
#+NAME: basic_query 
#+BEGIN_SRC SQL 
  SELECT name, grade FROM students 
#+END_SRC 

#+BEGIN_SRC python :export results :noweb yes :tangle yes
import sql_helper 
query = """
    <<basic_query>>
    """
query_status = sql_helper.run_query(query)  

#+END_SRC
```

My python is a little rusty, but at least if I tangle this to

```
import sql_helper 
query = """
    SELECT name, grade FROM students 

    """
query_status = sql_helper.run_query(query)
```

python does no longer complain about the syntax, but about the missing module sql_helper...

Comment: if `basic_query` were `example` instead of `src` then `#+BEGIN_SRC python :var query=basic_query` would have worked.