# Org-mode get the content of src block during export

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel, advising-functions, defadvice

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a snippet of JavaScript code that I want to both display in the HTML generated from an org document and I want that code to be executed in the HTML page. For a simplistic example, let it be something like

```
  #+NAME: block-name
  #+BEGIN_SRC javascript
  alert("Ding!");
  #+END_SRC

  #+NAME: insert-script
  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :export results
  (format "<script type=\"text/javascript\">%s</script>" block-name)
  #+END_SRC

  #+CALL: insert-script()
```

But this complains about undefined symbol `block-name`.

I've found this question, which is very similar, but the answer given there doesn't work for me. [Make the source code from one code block the input to another code block in Emacs org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074967/make-the-source-code-from-one-code-block-the-input-to-another-code-block-in-emac)

What is the syntax for referring to the content / name of the block?

**EDIT:**

I'm getting closer, but still not there:

```
   #+NAME: block-name
   #+BEGIN_SRC javascript :exports code
   alert("Ding!");
   #+END_SRC

   #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :var script=block-name
   (print (format "<script type=\"text/javascript\">%s</script>" script))
   #+END_SRC

   #+RESULTS:
```

This has two problems. The value of `script` variable is `nil` and the script tags are being escaped (angle brackets being replaced by `&lt;` and `&gt;`. I could find this particular case of replacement by putting the script tags outside the evaluation, but I won't be able to prevent this as a general rule (if there is a less-then or greater-then signs in the script, they will get replaced).

**EDIT1:**

Almost there!

Advised the `org-babel-get-src-block-info` to have it store locally the content of the block of code, if it is named into a variable `<name>-text`, so I can get it later.

```
(defadvice org-babel-get-src-block-info (after org-babel-store-info)
  (let* ((info-copy ad-return-value)
         (block-name (nth 4 info-copy))
         (block-text (nth 1 info-copy)))
    (when block-name
      (set (make-local-variable
            (intern (format "%s-text" block-name))) block-text))
    info-copy))
(ad-activate 'org-babel-get-src-block-info)
```

Example usage:

```
   #+NAME: block-name
   #+BEGIN_SRC javascript :exports code
   alert("Ding!");
   #+END_SRC

   #+NAME: insert-script
   #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :results html
     (print (format "<script type=\"text/javascript\">%s</script>"
                    block-name-text))
   #+END_SRC

   #+RESULTS:
```

The escaping is handled with `:results html` option - this causes Org to insert the HTML literally.

---

```
  #+NAME: math
  #+BEGIN_SRC js :exports none :noweb yes
    // Logarithm of base two:
    var y = Math.log(x) / Math.log(2);
  #+END_SRC

  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tagnle example :exports results :noweb yes :results html
    (print (format "<script>%s</script>" "<<math>>"))
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS:
```

Here's the minimal example that fails.

but this will work and produce the "expected" result:

```
  #+NAME: math
  #+BEGIN_SRC js :exports none :noweb yes
    // Logarithm of base two:
    var y = Math.log(x) / Math.log(2);
  #+END_SRC

  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tagnle example :exports both :noweb yes :results html
    ; <<math>>
    (print (format "<script>%s</script>" "your script could be here"))
  #+END_SRC
```

with the output of `<script>your script could be here</script>` and the JavaScript code in the comments of eLisp code block.

Answer (score 3):

Use a variable in your "insert-script", for example

```
:var data=block-name
```

if you want the *results* of block-name Inside your "insert-script".

If you want the *contents*, use the NoWeb notation, with ":noweb yes", that is use:

```
<<block-name>>
```

in your "insert-script".

Comment: Wait. There is another form for NoWeb: <<block-name()>> where you insert the results (!) of the evaluation of block-name. You can even pass parameters...

Comment: Is it normal that I did not get your comments by email?  I just see (by accident) that you commented my answer...

Answer (score -3):

```
#+BEGIN_HTML
<script>
    (function(){alert("ding !");})();
</script>
#+END_HTML
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add a comment or short statement that explains how this code answers the question.